# Magento Clear Cart Observer

Tags: magento, events, cart, checkout

Namespace_Modulename_Model_ObserverI need to create an event/observer to clear cart before a product is being added. The checkout process will include only one product. Could anybody give me a hand?

I have the following code so far, but I'm doing something wrong:

In config.xml I have:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
          <observers>
            <clear_cart_observer>
              <type>singleton</type>
              <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
              <method>clearCart</method>
            </clear_cart_observer>
          </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Also, I have created an observer file which contains:

```
public function clearCart($observer) 
{   
    foreach( Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getItemsCollection() as $item ) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->removeItem( $item->getId() )->save();
    }
}
```

I don't get any error in my system.log, but it doesn't trigger. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to fix this:

```
<class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
```

And ensure that you have the module loaded in:

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_Modulename.xml
```

Don't forget to flush cache.

Comment: That was ok in my code. Just that I did not paste it in here. Doesn't fix my p[roblem.

Comment: Put a die('here'); at the top of your observer. Does it render?